# PySpark: Read the csv data in pyspark frame. Why does it show special characters in frame? Any way to show in a tabular form except using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading the CSV file using pyspark. After reading the CSV into the pyspark dataframe it shows me as I have special characters in my header while displaying the data on jupyter notebook. Can anyone please guide me on how can I display data without seeing these special characters? Moreover the data is not aligned as you can see in the picture, how can I display data in the tabular form not like this (without using pandas)

```
py_df = spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv("E:\Data files\Amazon e-commerce data.csv")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try `truncate = False` in your `show()`

```
py_df = spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv("E:\Data files\Amazon e-commerce data.csv").show(truncate=False)
```

It will show only 20 rows, if you want to see more rows put `n=1000` for 1000 rows in `show()`

Answer (score 1):

You have too many columns to fit on one line, so the lines wrap. You can limit the number of columns that you show with a `.select()` before the show:

```
py_df.withColumn("Double the Price", py_df["price"] * 2).select(["price", "Double the Price").show(n=2)
```

Maybe jupyter notebook has better support for rendering pandas dataframes? If that's the case, you could try to convert the top of the spark dataframe to pandas dataframe:

```
py_df.withColumn("Double the Price", py_df["price"] * 2).limit(100).toPandas()
```